# SASL passthrough via LDAPS and Azure Active Directory Domain Services?

Tags: linux, openldap, entra-id, entra-domain-services

I have an on-prem OpenLDAP instance which is used to authenticate all of our Linux users (around 1000) and handle any Web based authentication. The user accounts and POSIX attributes are housed in LDAP while any password authentication is handed off via SASL passthrough to an off-site Active Directory instance (over LDAPS of course).

The organization housing the AD instance is slowly moving to Azure for everything and the question is can the LDAP server continue functioning as our authentication source if users are in Azure?

From what I've read, it sounds like SASL passthrough might be possible with Azure Active Directory Domain Services (there is an LDAP service wrapped up in AADDS). Can anyone confirm/offer insight? My background is in Linux so I'm not as familiar with the current Windows tech.